# Generate system sounds in linux through c/c++ program

Tags: c++, c, linux, beep, system-sounds

I am capturing frames from a camera at the rate of 1 Frame Per Sec in a `while(1)` loop.

I want to generate a beep sound of 100ms duration in my C program each time, when a particular condition is satisfied inside the `while(1)` loop.

I tried playing a single-tone .wav file using `aplay` shell command, but it is slowing down the program.

Is there any alternative which is less time-consuming?

Is there any way to produce system sounds (e.g. the sound which is played when we press right arrow key in the terminal) using a C/C++ program?

**Edited:**
I am able to generate beep sound though internal pc speakers using two methods:

Method 1: Using beep command by enabling pcspeaker:

> `sudo modprobe pcspkr`
>
> `sudo beep`

Method 2: Using command: `xkbbell -force`

But I did not find any solution other than `aplay` and `paplay` commands. When I try to play a sound file using these commands, there is some delay after playing sound file and returning control to user in shell.

Comment: Do you have a hardware `PC speaker`? If not, you need to emulate it

Comment: As suggest by answer print("\a"); works. It emulates the PC speaker on Windows, surely would do the same on Linux (though not confirm)

Comment: I am using external speakers. Also, printf("\a") is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can for example print out the ASCII bell character to get a beep sound.

```
printf("\a");
```

Comment: Its not working. No sound is coming through external/internal speakers. Program just exits quietly.

Comment: I think beep sound has to be activated (cf. http://superuser.com/questions/22767/enable-system-beep-in-ubuntu for Ubuntu).

Comment: I have activated it and now able to generate sound through internal pc speaker. But I want sound to come out through external speakers.